# Установка MS SQL сервера

Tags: java, sql-server

Столкнулся с проблемой установки MS SQL сервера на ноутбук. Требует установить Oracle JRE 7 Update 51
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки Java Runtime выдаёт ту же ошибку. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: А Вам точно нужна функциональность Polybase?

Comment: *После установки Java Runtime выдаёт ту же ошибку.* Во-первых, проверьте, что JRE установлен нужной версии (случаи, когда пц свежая версия не распознаётся - обычное дело). Во-вторых, проверьте настройки JRE, особенно вкладку безопасности, и разрешите как минимум локалхост без ограничений (в белый список его).